# Logging in ServiceStack

Tags: logging, servicestack

I'm trying to figure out if ServiceStack writes any logs, and if it does how would someone plug into it to capture or redirect it to a logging framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ServiceStack uses the [ServiceStack.Logging abstract logging framework](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Logging) which currently has  5 different .NET logging providers available on NuGet and Github:

- [ServiceStack.Logging.NLog](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Logging.NLog)
- [ServiceStack.Logging.Elmah](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Logging.Elmah)
- [ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net)
- [ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Netv129](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Netv129)
- [ServiceStack.Logging.EventLog](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Logging.EventLog)

The ConsoleLogger and DebugLogger and are already built-in into ServiceStack and bind to .NET Framework's Console and Debug loggers.

Comment: I always thought those are there to be used by projects that are using service stack rather than ServiceStack it self. something similar to Common.Logging

Comment: `LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory();` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Another neat and totally undocumented feature is that if you have it hooked up to Redis, it automatically maintains a rolling error log for you.